# Build phonegap to file .apk for android

Tags: android, html, cordova

I am using phonegap to code a game HTML5 for android.

I run the game at http://app.phonegap.com/, it runs well on my phone.

But when I build to file .apk to install: it's not fully working, some bug ( detail: error canvas, request window frame ), it not show.

I build to .apk by commandline: `cordova build android --release`

How to fix ?
Thank all

Comment: It would be better if you provide the code where the errors are coming and also the logcat of the errors.

Comment: Hi, my code is complex, but why when i run by tool from app.phonegap.com, it run well on my phone. but when build to file .apk it run error: canvas not working.

Comment: I cannot guess the problem based on this.

Comment: Which version of Android is your phone running?

Comment: hi, both android 4.2.2 and 4.4.2 :)

Comment: i am using window.requestAnimationFrame to code game HTML5 for android.